# Setting up Daily Grafana Loki Alert, If no log seen by 4:25 AM, each day

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-alerts

I'm trying to trigger an alert using Grafana Loki. If no log seen by 5AM, each day need to trigger an alert.

Here is the query I came up with. I dont think its correct as the `offset 16h25m`: shifts the time range by 16 hours and 25 minutes.

```
count_over_time({env="dev", app="test-app"} |="YOUR Test Keyword" [1d] offset 16h25m) == 0
```

Any Grafana Loki expert who has any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to only check for alerts on mondays 4:25 ish:

```
sum(count_over_time({app="my-service"} | label_format day=`{{ __timestamp__.Weekday }}` | label_format hour=`{{ __timestamp__.Hour }}` | label_format minute=`{{ __timestamp__.Minute }}`  | hour = 4 and day = "Monday" and minute > 25 and minute < 35 [5m])) > 0
```

This creates labels for day, hour and minute and only returns anything when it is Monday, 9:30 UTC. It uses golang time formatting (https://www.pauladamsmith.com/blog/2011/05/go_time.html) to do that. Its a bit finicky and there might be a different way using predefined methods.